# Display view in a scroll view on screen

Tags: android

In my activity I have a scroll view which contains a linear layout that has many views. Is there a way I can display a specific view (from the linear layout) when starting this activity? By default this view is hidden, so I must scroll the scroll view to make it visible.

Answer (score 4):

Scroll the view to the view you want to show:

```
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, specificView.getTop())
```

See [Is there a way to programmatically scroll a scroll view to a specific edit text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831671/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-scroll-a-scroll-view-to-a-specific-edit-text)

Comment: View.getTop() was what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

see [setVisibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility) for details

Comment: I think you're answering for another question.

Comment: Let's say that I have a scroll view with 100 views, but maximum 4 views are visible at a certain moment. To see other views you have to scroll, right? Well, I would like the scroll view to be scrolled, when the, activity is displayde,  to a specific view (89, for exxample). It has nothing to do with the setVisibility method.

Comment: ok! Thanks for the comment. Did you try [requestFocus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus%28%29)?