# Android/Intent equivalent of HTTP #anchor

Tags: android, android-intent

I realize the title is confusing, but I'm not sure how to summarize my problem.

So in HTML, you can have a webpage

`reallyLongWebpage.html`

And when you open it in a browser it opens it at the top of the document. But if, instead, you navigate to

`reallyLongWebpage.html#section46`

then it will open the webpage, but scroll down to whereever `<a name="section46"></a>` is on the page.

I'm trying to do a similar thing with my android app.

I have an activity with a fair amount of content (not a huge amount, but still a little too much to scroll down every time to find what you want). I know how to use intents and send parameters, but on the activity itself, how do I take the value (e.g. "scroll to anchor 7") and scroll to the appropriate positon?

Comment: Does your activity contain a list view?  Is it the ListView that you wish to scroll?

Comment: It does not contain a list view. It is mostly TextViews with a few images here and there. All the headings (which I want to be anchors) are separate TextViews.

Comment: Darn.  I was just in the process of composing an answer for list views :-(

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831671/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-scroll-a-scroll-view-to-a-specific-edit-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a ListView in the Activity you wish to scroll, then

a) In the intent that launches the activity, send the index of the dataset item as an extra

```
int indexToSelect = 17;
intent.putExtra("IndexToSelect", indexToSelect);
```

b) In the activity itself, get the index from the intent

```
int indexToSelect = intent.getIntExtra("IndexToSelect");
```

c) Finally, scroll the ListView to that position:

```
listView.setSelectionFromTop(indexToSelect, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer really depends on what you are scrolling exactly, but if you are using `ScrollView`, then you can use `.scrollTo(int, int)` ([see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)).

To retrieve the scroll coordinates or search text from the `Intent`, it should be placed inside the data `Bundle` before it is sent.

If you are not using preordained coordinates and searching for some particular text, you will just need to check each `TextView`'s contents and compare. It may be helpful to use `setTag` and `getTag` to specify which `TextView`'s are considered searchable headers.