# Android scrollTo(0,0) action on click

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Hello I am really new on android development and I would like to ask a simple question.

I have a button (buttonR2C1).
When I click the buttonR2C1 I change the text of my textView (the textview is included inside a scrollView).The problem is that the position of the scrollView remains the same.

I would like to add an action that brings my ScrollView in position 0,0 by using the scrollTo action.

Can anyone help me achieve this?

.java

```
    final TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainL1R2);
    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonR2C1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            tv2.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.L1R2C1));
        }
    });
```

.xml

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonR2C1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Capitolo 1"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainL1R2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="CustomText"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:text="@string/L1R2C1"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
```

Comment: I tried to add     


 tv2.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {  
             tv2.scrollTo(0,0);
            }
        });


but nothing happens..

Comment: What's your problem exactly, it seems like you already know what to do?

Comment: Finally I figured out by myself.

on .java file I add

    final ScrollView sv2 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
and this inside the onClick

             sv2.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {  
                        sv2.scrollTo(0,0);
                    }
                });
and it works as a charm!!

Hope that would help others too.

Comment: thanks Ascorbin for your response...seems like it works that way ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the scrollTo method of the ScrollView, not the TextView, like

```
   final ScrollView scr = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
   scr.scrollTo(x, y);
```

To scroll exactly to your TextView, you'll have to get the position of the TextView.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831671/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-scroll-a-scroll-view-to-a-specific-edit-text) answer.