# Last item of scroll view is hidden and when expanded, its not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` like :

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/place_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@mipmap/tourist_place_details" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/images"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_imagegallery" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minWidth="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@mipmap/icon_clock" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_time"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="9:00am - 6:00pm"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_categories" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@color/divider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minWidth="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@mipmap/icon_fare" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_fare"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Adult 10/-  Child 5/-  Tourist 100/-"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_categories" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@color/divider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minWidth="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_location" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_address"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="blah balh blah"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_categories" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@color/divider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:minWidth="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@mipmap/icon_call" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_contact_numbers"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="+1 999999999999"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_categories" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@color/divider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/image_map"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@color/divider" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_about"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/about"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_categories" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_desc"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
    android:visibility="gone"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:text="asdkjsadkja adslkgsadkjbsakd asdkjsadkja aldsgsakjdbdlkashdkjsabhdk lashdlksajd asdhkj asdkj askjd asjhd lakjhsbd asdkjsadkja adslkgsadkjbsakd aldsgsakjdbdlkashdkjsabhdk lashdlksajd asdhkj asdkj askjd asjhd lakjhsbd "
            android:textColor="@color/gray_categories" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The "About" `TextView` is visible and the `txt_desc` is hidden.
on clicking the About, 'm making the `txt_desc` visible with animation slide down using following method :

```
public static void expand(final View v) {
    v.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    // Older versions of android (pre API 21) cancel animations for views
    // with a height of 0.
    v.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
                                           Transformation t) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1 ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration((int) (targetHeight / v.getContext().getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics().density));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

The `TextView` `txt_desc` is expanding but not visible as the `ScrollView` stays at About and below `txt_desc` content is not being shown. If we scroll, the content is visible.

Can anyone help on making the `txt_desc` visible after making it visible.

I have already used `scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);`, but no use

Comment: you check without animation

Comment: either with animation or without animation, About is last item of scrollview. so even if I'm making the txt_desc visible, the scrollview stays at About. If I scroll, I can see it

Comment: v.setFocusable(true); use it

Comment: this link might help you to scroll to specific widget http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831671/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-scroll-a-scroll-view-to-a-specific-edit-text

Comment: @Shishram, it worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

set `layout_height` of `ScrollView` to `match_parent` and `paddingBottom` to `10dp`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I used NestedScrollView to solve the problem.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

If you use scrollview with tablayout then you might experiance the problem that the tablayout is not going up if you scroll the content. NestedScrollView solves this problem as well.

Comment: and for androidx use androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Do not use padding in ScrollView or NestedScrollView

ScrollView can only host one child. Put margins or paddings in its child.