# Softkeyboard hides button below multi-line EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-relativelayout, android-softkeyboard

I have a `RelativeLayout` with an `EditText` that has a `Button` below it. Ideally as the user clicks the `EditText` and fills in multiple lines of text, the `RelativeLayout` would also expand as the lines increase. However, the behavior I have now is that after the first line of the `EditText` is filled, the keyboard begins to cover the `Button` below it and after 3-4 lines of text in the `EditText`, the `Button` is gone below the keyboard. Is there any way to have it so that as I type in text, the entire layout increases in size so that the button stays above the keyboard? Here is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        android:name="<Name of project>.activity.Comments"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="Comments"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
```

Comments.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/send_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <EditText
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:id="@+id/write_comment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:textColorHint="@color/material_color_grey_300"
            android:hint="@string/commentBack"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:maxLength="200"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

        <Button
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:id="@+id/send_comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_below="@id/write_comment"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried to add `android:isScrollContainer="true"` thinking that it would create a scroll container to the `EditText` so that it would help expand the layout but that didn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Added in entire layout based on answer below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/comments_layout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/comments_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/comments_listview"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rv_view_comments">
            </ListView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_below="@id/rv_view_comments"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:id="@+id/empty_list_item"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text="@string/noComments" >
            </TextView>

            <include layout="@layout/include_progress_overlay"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/send_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <EditText
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:id="@+id/write_comment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:textColorHint="@color/material_color_grey_300"
        android:hint="@string/commentBack"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:maxLength="200"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

    <Button
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:id="@+id/send_comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/send"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_below="@id/write_comment"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />
</RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Edit: As per Jaydroider's request, I have included a photo to show my problem. If I could make a GIF or something, if I add more text to my `EditText` field, the `Send` button will disappear under the keyboard and unless I remove text from the `EditText`, the `Send cannot be pushed:

[image: Image showing problem]

Edit: I have also shown how I scroll to the bottom of my `ListView` when I click on the `EditText` here if this helps.

```
public void setupComment(final EditText comment) {
        //Once we send the post, we want to scroll to bottom of listview
        comment.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                                          KeyEvent event) {
                if (event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    comment.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
                    resetKeyboardSettings();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        //Hide the cursor until view is clicked on
        View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Touched");
                if (v.getId() == comment.getId()) {
                    comment.setCursorVisible(true);
                }
                commentsView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        commentsView.smoothScrollToPosition(commentsView.getAdapter().getCount());
                    }
                }, 750);
                return false;
            }
        };
        comment.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
    }
```

Comment: When i have checked your layout i only able to see `List View` no any other widgets. Please elaborate more.

Comment: @jaydroider I have updated the above code to demonstrate my problem. Hopefully that helps. It is under the edit that says `Edit: Added in entire layout based on answer below:`

Comment: Yes i have already checked that layout my side i need clarification about where `edit text` and `button` will shown. with that layout currently i can only be able to see `List View`.

Comment: Could you provide a screen shot what your design looks like exactly ?

Comment: @jaydroider I have provided a screen show showing my design. Hope that helps.

Comment: Check my answer below and let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried with your `Layout` everything is perfect with that not an issue.

> `But you need to make changes to your manifest where you declared your activity` using more properties to `android:configChanges`.
>
> Do this inside your `android manifest.xml` file.

```
     <activity
            android:name="<Name of project>.activity.Comments"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="Comments"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"/>
```

*Here is XML which i used*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/comments_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/comments_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/comments_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/send_message"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/rv_view_comments"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/empty_list_item"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/empty_list_item"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rv_view_comments"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="No Comments"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/send_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="4dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/write_comment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:hint="Comment Back"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:maxLength="200"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send_comment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/write_comment"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:text="Send"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`I have tested with above changes and it's just working fine you can see below.`

[image]

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Hey, do you mind posting your code just so that I could mimic it? I tried to listen to your changes on the `Manifest` file but that didn't seem to fix it for me.

Comment: Your XML layout code that you used to create the image above?

Comment: Hey I actually tried out your code and it seemed to work for me. Thanks for all your help! I think I had to fix a few things on the button gravity and also had to make the `RelativeLayout` `wrap_content`. Thanks!

Comment: @user1871869 Cheers. Upvote the answer also so will be helpful to others in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/send_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <EditText
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:id="@+id/write_comment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:textColorHint="@color/material_color_grey_300"
            android:hint="@string/commentBack"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:maxLength="200"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

        <Button
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:id="@+id/send_comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_below="@id/write_comment"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hey, I tried to follow your code. It seems like you just added `android:layout_height = wrap_content` in the  `RelativeLayout` tag. I have tried to implement your suggestion but that didn't seem to work and now the `ListView` I have covers my `EditText` I posted my entire layout above in hopes that it would be more clear and could help me fix this problem. I tried what you mentioned above but because the `EditText` was hidden, I wasn't sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your edit texts and button in a scroll view.

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
               <Edittext
               <EditText
               <EditText
               <Btn
             </LinearLayout
        </scrollview
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be adding `ScrollView` as a root view in your layout and Override View's [onSizeChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method. If height of `EditText` increases and Keyboard is blocking your button, [Smooth Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831671/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-scroll-a-scroll-view-to-a-specific-edit-text) to your button.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would I have a `ScrollView` with a nested `ListView` in it though? I see what you are saying but I feel like that would not work in my case.