# Going to a specific part of the app in android

Tags: java, android

By using an anchor tag on html i can go to specific part of the page as long as i have the ID of foo.

```
<a href="#foo">Jump to #foo on same page</a>
```

Is there a way in android where i can implement a feature like that on menu?

For example i click one option on menu and then i will go to a specific content (like a TextView) of the app.

I tried searching but i don't know what terms i will use to search.

I'm new to android Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try using clickableSpan,check this article it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to programmatically scroll a scroll view to a specific edit text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831671/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-scroll-a-scroll-view-to-a-specific-edit-text)

Comment: @JensV how can I implement it when i click one option on menu and then i will go to the TextVjew

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app