# Android ScrollView with custom scrolling from TextView1 to TextView2

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-scrollview

I have a huge vertical ScrollView which contains many TextViews and ShapableImageViews.
The standard ScrollView allows a smooth scrolling. But I want to have it like this in my app:

As soon as the user scrolls, there should be no smooth scrolling, but it should automatically scroll from TextView1 to TextView2. When the user scrolls down again, it should automatically scroll to TextView3. And when user scrolls up, it should go back from TextView3 to TextView2.

How do I achieve that custom scrolling behavior?
I use Kolin, but also a help with Java code would be very appreciated.

This is my XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="isData"
            type="com.example.ezworkshop.TutorialData" />


    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".view.TutorialActivity"
        android:background="#25261D">
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView_activityTutorial"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

                    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                        android:imageUrl="@{isData.image}"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="220dp"
                        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_playButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/playbutton"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialHeading"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialHeading}"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:textSize="26sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText2"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText2}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText3"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText3}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage2"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage2}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText4"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText4}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage3"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage3}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText5"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText5}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage4"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage4}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText6"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText6}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage5"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage5}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText7"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText7}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage6"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage6}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText8"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText8}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage7"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage7}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText9"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText9}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage8"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage8}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText10"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText10}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage9"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage9}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText11"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText11}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage10"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage10}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText12"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText12}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage11"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage11}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText13"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText13}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage12"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage12}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText14"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText14}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage13"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage13}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText15"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText15}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage14"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage14}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText16"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText16}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage15"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage15}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText17"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText17}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage16"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage16}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText18"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText18}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage17"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage17}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText19"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText19}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage18"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage18}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialText20"
                    android:text="@{isData.tutorialText20}"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standardTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tutorialTextImage19"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:imageUrl="@{isData.tutorialTextImage19}"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCornerForImageView"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </ScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to programmatically scroll a scroll view to a specific edit text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831671/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-scroll-a-scroll-view-to-a-specific-edit-text)

Comment: Hi, already found this post before, but it does not really answer my question due the fact that the codes in this post are not related to an on touch function...

Comment: Your layout design is redundant. I suggest to put your tutorial texts and image urls into a list and implement a `RecyclerView`. Additional benefit is you can use `RecyclerView.SnapHelper` to handle scrolling behavior you want.